# Instant image loading using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

well I was searching on internet the way to load images instantly using Jquery, but I didn't found anything.
For that I would like to use:

```
<select>
       <option>Image 1</option>
       <option>Image 2</option>
       <option>Image 3</option>
</select>
```

So basically  I want load A image Instantly after clicking on one of the Option.
How Can I do it? Thank you.

EDIT
After clicking on one of the option I would load image, without refreshing the page

Comment: Yes sorry, After clicking on one of the option I would load image, without refreshing the page.

Comment: Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/rt9sj6fy/

Comment: @blex you should post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```js
// When an option is selected
$('#imageSelect').on('change',function(){
    // Change the image's src to the selected value
    $('#myImage').attr('src', $(this).val());
  // Do it once on page load if necessary
}).change();
```

```css
img{display:block;max-width: 50%;} /* Just for the demo */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="imageSelect">
       <option value="http://i62.tinypic.com/2088l0l.jpg">Image 1</option>
       <option value="http://i58.tinypic.com/2rfv4b6.jpg">Image 2</option>
       <option value="http://i62.tinypic.com/9a7nk4.jpg">Image 3</option>
</select>

<!-- Your image holder -->
<img src="" id="myImage" alt="" />
```